# When apply CIFilter happen ERRORS iOS

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

When used CoreImage (Framework) and apply CIFilter
happens many of errors

```
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 12
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 14
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 16
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 14
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 16
```

These errors happen in `CIContext` at this line:

```
[Context drawImage:background atPoint:CGPointZero fromRect:[image extent]];
```

-> THIS Errors not appear when apply filter  on one image

```
    image = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"kCICategoryNonSquarePixels" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, @"inputColor0", [CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.2 blue:0.0], @"inputColor1", [CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0], nil].outputImage;
```

-> this errors appear when apply filter on two image

```
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];



CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMinimumCompositing"];

[filter setValue:background forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
[filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

background = [filter outputImage];
[coreImageContext drawImage:background atPoint:CGPointZero fromRect:[background extent]];

    [self.context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

ANY HELP PLEASE ??